# What are exchanges like "How are you," "I'm fine," and "See you later" called?

Tags: idioms, terminology, politeness, conversation, greetings

Some verbal/written exchanges convey almost no meaning but are part of the protocol of conversation.  For example, somebody greets you with "How are you?" and they're not usually not listening for actual information, just for you to say, "Fine," or similar.  Or when you go through any sort of service transaction, it seems like half a dozen "thank yous" are exchanged between both parties.

Is there a term or phrase describing the phrases we use for maintaining the facade of politeness?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an example of [**phatic** communication](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phatic):

> **phatic** [ˈfætɪk] adj (Linguistics) (of speech, esp of conversational phrases) used to establish social contact and to express sociability rather than specific meaning

Comment: Nice.  Never heard of that before.  Sounds spot-on.

Comment: ...or the noun "phaticism".

Comment: Is that related to **emphatic**?

Comment: @Martha F.: Surprisingly they come from different but similar-sounding Greek roots: *phatic* from "phatos ‘spoken’ or phatikos ‘affirming’" and *emphatic* (via *emphasis*) "from emphainein ‘exhibit,’ from em- ‘in, within’ + phainein ‘to show'."

Comment: Sadly I'll have to -1... nobody would say a couple people were exchanging "phatics"!

Comment: @Mehrdad: That is not germane to the issue at all. OP asked what such communication is called.

Comment: @Robusto: I mean, when someone asks what something is "called", the answer to that question should be a noun, right? Like if someone says what the thing you hold next to your head to talk to someone is, the correct answer wouldn't be "wireless", "wireless communication", or "wireless telephony"; it'd be "phone", "cell phone", or "mobile phone".

Comment: @Mehrdad: OK, now you're officially not making sense. Good day.

Comment: @Robusto: What part of what I said didn't make any sense?

Answer (score 13):

They are called **pleasantries.**  From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pleasantries):

> pleas·ant·ry (*n.*)
>   1. A humorous remark or act; a jest.
>   2. **A polite social utterance**; a civility.
>   3. A good-humored or playful manner in conversation or social relations.

Comment: I thought pleasantries were things like discussing the weather or latest celebrity gossip.  Is there a term for the punctuation-like phrases lubricating conversation?

Comment: @Jacob: Those _are_ included in the term pleasantries. If you want something more specific, than "Greetings" cover the hellos and how-are-yous. "Farewells" would be anything at the ends and "manners" would cover saying "Thank you" and "You're welcome."

Answer (score 5):

It just occurred to me that "formalities" is what I was looking for.

Comment: _Formalities_ seems an overbroad term to me compared to _pleasantries_.  Not to be too strong -- it's clear that the sets of pleasantries and formalities intersect substantially and meaningfully -- but there members of both sets that cannot be included in the other.  Kow-towing towards the Emperor of China, for example, would be a formality, and not a pleasantry, and not what you asked for above; kow-towing is not "part of the protocol of conversation."

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the extent of the conversation "small talk" might be applicable too. This would cover not just the formalities (which are specifically things that are necessary, not just chit-chat) but the ensuing social niceties, banter that helps to fill what would otherwise be potentially awkward silence or whatever business was to be conducted.

That's about five answers right there.